# Multiple drag and drop in PyQt4

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, pyqt, pyqt4

i can't find an example on dragging (and dropping) multiple elements with Qt/PyQt;
In my case i need to drag elements from this QTableView:

```
class DragTable(QTableView):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(DragTable, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setDragEnabled(True)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasFormat("application/pubmedrecord"):
            event.setDropAction(Qt.MoveAction)
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def startDrag(self, event):
        print type(event)
        index = self.indexAt(event.pos())
        if not index.isValid():
            return

        selected = index.row()
        bstream = cPickle.dumps(selected)
        mimeData = QMimeData()
        mimeData.setData("application/pubmedrecord", bstream)
        drag = QDrag(self)
        drag.setMimeData(mimeData)
        pixmap = QPixmap(":/drag.png")

        drag.setHotSpot(QPoint(pixmap.width()/3, pixmap.height()/3))
        drag.setPixmap(pixmap)
        result = drag.start(Qt.MoveAction)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.startDrag(event)
```

To this QLabel (My dropzone):

```
class TagLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, text, color, parent = None):
        super(TagLabel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.tagColor = color
        self.setText(text)
        self.setStyleSheet("QLabel { background-color: %s; font-size: 14pt; }" % self.tagColor)
        self.defaultStyle = self.styleSheet()
        self.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter|Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasFormat("application/pubmedrecord"):
            self.set_bg(True)
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.reject()

    def dragLeaveEvent(self, event):
        self.set_bg(False)
        event.accept()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        self.set_bg(False)
        data = event.mimeData()
        bstream = data.retrieveData("application/pubmedrecord", QVariant.ByteArray)
        selected = pickle.loads(bstream.toByteArray())
        event.accept()
        self.emit(SIGNAL("dropAccepted(PyQt_PyObject)"), (selected, str(self.text()), str(self.tagColor)))

    def set_bg(self, active = False):
        if active:
            style = "QLabel {background: yellow; font-size: 14pt;}"
            self.setStyleSheet(style)
        else:
            self.setStyleSheet(self.defaultStyle)
```

Any tips? Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a full working example:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, Qt
import cPickle
import pickle
```

Why are you using `cPickle` as well as `pickle`?

```
class DragTable(QtGui.QTableView):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(DragTable, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.setSelectionBehavior(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
```

You probably want to set the selection behavior here, because I'm assuming row-based data presentation.  You may of course change that.

```
    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasFormat("application/pubmedrecord"):
            event.setDropAction(Qt.MoveAction)
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def startDrag(self, event):
```

Your code assumes only one index here, based on the event position.  For a `QTableView`, this is unnecessary, as it already handles the mouse click itself.  Instead, it's better to depend on Qt to provide you with the information that you actually *need*, as always.  Here, I've chose to use `selectedIndexes()`.

```
        indices = self.selectedIndexes()
```

Indices is now a list of `QModelIndex` instances, that I chose to convert to a set of row numbers.  It's also possible to convert these to a list of `QPersistentModelIndex`es, depending on your needs.

One thing that may surprise you here, is that indices contains indexes for all *cells* in the table, not all rows, regardless of the selection behavior.  That's why I chose to use a `set` instead of a `list`.

```
        selected = set()
        for index in indices:
            selected.add(index.row())
```

I left the rest untouched, assuming that you know what you're doing there.

```
        bstream = cPickle.dumps(selected)
        mimeData = QtCore.QMimeData()
        mimeData.setData("application/pubmedrecord", bstream)
        drag = QtGui.QDrag(self)
        drag.setMimeData(mimeData)
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(":/drag.png")

        drag.setHotSpot(QtCore.QPoint(pixmap.width()/3, pixmap.height()/3))
        drag.setPixmap(pixmap)
        result = drag.start(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.startDrag(event)


class TagLabel(QtGui.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, text, color, parent = None):
        super(TagLabel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.tagColor = color
        self.setText(text)
        self.setStyleSheet("QLabel { background-color: %s; font-size: 14pt; }" % self.tagColor)
        self.defaultStyle = self.styleSheet()
        self.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasFormat("application/pubmedrecord"):
            self.set_bg(True)
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.reject()

    def dragLeaveEvent(self, event):
        self.set_bg(False)
        event.accept()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        self.set_bg(False)
        data = event.mimeData()
        bstream = data.retrieveData("application/pubmedrecord", QtCore.QVariant.ByteArray)
        selected = pickle.loads(bstream.toByteArray())
        event.accept()
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("dropAccepted(PyQt_PyObject)"), (selected, str(self.text()), str(self.tagColor)))
```

Unless you are interfacing with C++-code with this signal, it's not necessary to add a signal argument here, you may also use `dropAccepted` without parentheses and PyQt4 will do the right thing.

```
    def set_bg(self, active = False):
        if active:
            style = "QLabel {background: yellow; font-size: 14pt;}"
            self.setStyleSheet(style)
        else:
            self.setStyleSheet(self.defaultStyle)



app = QtGui.QApplication([])

l = TagLabel("bla bla bla bla bla bla bla", "red")
l.show()

m = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
for _ in xrange(4):
    m.appendRow([QtGui.QStandardItem(x) for x in ["aap", "noot", "mies"]])

t = DragTable()
t.setModel(m)
t.show()

def h(o):
    print "signal handled", o
l.connect(l, QtCore.SIGNAL("dropAccepted(PyQt_PyObject)"), h)

app.exec_()
```

Comment: Nice explanation, i couldn't ask for more :) Thanks!

Comment: Why does this not work with a QListWidget in place of the QLabel?

Comment: Ok, it works, but only if you use setDragDropMode(4) on the QListWidget.